# returning NULL for an object that will try to be used? (get core dump -- C++ newbie)

Tags: c++, oop

okkk, well i had to rewrite all my code and my post so i hope i get help.  i have two classes: PersonManager and Person.  the PersonManager's purpose is to keep track of all the Persons and the Persons' names.  here is my full code:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class Person
{
public:
  Person();
  void SetName(string s) {Name_ = s;}
  string GetName() const {return Name_;}
private:
  string Name_;
};

Person::Person()
{
  Name_ = "";
}

class PersonManager
{
public:
  PersonManager();
  void NewPerson(string);
  void GetRidOfPerson(string);
  Person *GetPerson(string);
  void Close();
private:
  map<string, Person *> PersonMap_;
};

PersonManager::PersonManager()
{
  PersonMap_.clear();
}

void PersonManager::NewPerson(string name)
{
  for (map<string, Person *>::iterator it = PersonMap_.begin();
       it != PersonMap_.end();
       it++)
    {
      if (it->first.compare(name) == 0)
    {
      return; // person already exists
    }
    }

  Person *person = new Person;
  PersonMap_.insert(pair<string, Person *>(name, person));
  cout << "Created person: " << name << ".\n";
}

Person *PersonManager::GetPerson(string name)
{
  for (map<string, Person *>::iterator it = PersonMap_.begin();
       it != PersonMap_.end();
       it++)
    {
      if (it->first.compare(name) == 0)
    {
      return it->second;
    }
    }

  cout << "Person: " << name << " not found." << endl;
  return NULL;
}

void PersonManager::GetRidOfPerson(string name)
{
  for (map<string, Person *>::iterator it = PersonMap_.begin();
       it != PersonMap_.end();
       it++)
    {
      if (it->first.compare(name) == 0)
    {
      delete it->second;
      PersonMap_.erase(it);
      cout << "Deleted person: " << name << ".\n";
      return;
    }
    }

  cout << "Couldn't find person " << name << " for deletion.\n";
}

void PersonManager::Close()
{
  for (map<string, Person *>::iterator it = PersonMap_.begin();
       it != PersonMap_.end();
       it++)
    {
      delete it->second;
      PersonMap_.erase(it);
      cout << "Deleted person: " << it->first << ".\n";
    }

  PersonMap_.clear();
}

int main(void)
{
  PersonManager person_manager;
  person_manager.NewPerson("Tom");
  person_manager.NewPerson("Tom");
  person_manager.GetRidOfPerson("Tom");
  person_manager.GetRidOfPerson("Abel");
  person_manager.GetPerson("Tom")->SetName("Bob");
  cout << person_manager.GetPerson("Tom")->GetName() << endl;
  cout << person_manager.GetPerson("Bob")->GetName() << endl;
  person_manager.Close();
  return 0;
}
```

all of the code in the main() function that checks for people that aren't in the list is for testing purposes!

if you do

```
person_manager.NewPerson("Tom");
```

and then you do

```
person_manager.GetPerson("Tom")->SetName("Billy");
```

and then try doing:

```
person_manager.GetPerson("Tom")->GetName();
```

it will return NULL, and then segfault.

so in this snippet:

```
Person *PersonManager::GetPerson(string name)
{
  for (map<string, Person *>::iterator it = PersonMap_.begin();
       it != PersonMap_.end();
       it++)
    {
      if (it->first.compare(name) == 0)
    {
      return it->second;
    }
    }

  cout << "Person: " << name << " not found." << endl;
  return NULL;
}
```

so i came up with a solution:

```
Person *person = new Person;
return person;
```

the problem is with ^ that, is that i have unallocated memory.  is there any other way to do this?

all help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You may want to rename PersonManager::PersonGinger().

Comment: There's a potentially offensive method name.

Comment: while i was renaming i didn't see that one...sorry.  i'll fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several issues.  First, at least from what I understand of your
code, the key used in `PersonManager::PersonMap_` is totally independent
of any data in the actual `Person`.  So the sequence:

```
person_manager.NewPerson("Tom");
person_manager.GetPerson("Tom")->SetName("Billy")
std::cout << person_manager.GetPerson("Tom")->GetName() << std::endl;
```

is perfectly valid, and outputs "Billy".  That may not be what you want,
but that's what you've written.

Your test code in `main` fails, of course, because you access the
results of `person_manager.GetPerson("Tom")` after having done 
`person_manager.GetRidOfPerson("Tom")`.

More generally, from appearances, I would guess that you are trying to
key off the name of the person.  In this case, I would make the name
field in `Person` immutable, and require it to be initialized in the
constructor.  Having done that, I can either use `std::set` (with a
comparison function based on the name), or if all `Person` are created
in `PersonManager`, I can guarantee the invariant that the key in
`std::map` is always equalt to the name field in the corresponding
`Person`.

Secondly, any time you access any sort of associative data, you have to
be prepared for the case where the element doesn't exist.  There are
many ways of handling this:

- Automaticall insert it, with some default value.  (This is the
  behavior of `std::map` if you use `[]` to access the element.)
- Return some default value without inserting it.
- Return some sort of sentinal—returning pointers, with a null
  pointer as sentinal, is a wide spread convention.
- Raise an exception.  A valid choice if not finding the value can be
  considered exceptional.
- Abort the program.  A valid choice if the presence of the value can be
  considered a precondion (not often the case).

If the key is a string read from an external data source, the last two
cases are probably not applicable (although it depends somewhat on the
data source for the exception).  Nor is the first, really; with a
corrupt data source (or a stubborn user, if the data source is
interactive input), you'll soon end up with a map containing mostly
default values.  Most of the time, the second or third solution impose,
with the second only valid if the default value is easily recognized as
a miss.  And the client code **must** check that the lookup succeeded
before proceding (just as client code must check that input succeeds
before proceding).

So in your case, either you return a null pointer (which client code
must check for before continuing—that's the rule for most
functions returning a pointer); or you return a reference, returning a
reference to a static variable or a member of `PersonManager` in case of
failure; this second is only valid if you can define a unique *invalid*
instance of `Person`.  Or, depending on where the key values are coming
from in your final application, you might consider throwing an
exception if the value isn't present.  But you have to do something, and
the client code must be able to handle the case where a key value isn't
present.  There's no way around this.

Comment: i don't need this anymore but lots of information thanks i will use later

Answer (score 2):

Instead of returning having a map with pointers to `Person`, have actual instances of the class and then return a reference. If no `Person` can be found, then return a static member variable, similar to what `map<>::end()` does.

Something like this:

```
class PersonManager
{
public:
  // ...
  Person &GetPerson(string);

  static Person NoSuchPerson;

private:
  map<string, Person> PersonMap_;
};

Person PersonManager::NoSuchPerson;

Person &PersonManager::GetPerson(string name)
{
  for (map<string, Person>::iterator it = PersonMap_.begin();
       it != PersonMap_.end();
       it++)
    {
      if (it->first.compare(name) == 0)
        {
          return it->second;
        }
    }

  cout << "Person: " << name << " not found." << endl;
  return NoSuchPerson;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if the value returned from `GetPerson` is `NULL` before you use it. Something along the lines of this:

```
Person *person = person_manager.GetPerson("Tom");
if (person == NULL) {
    std::cout << "Tom not found!" << std::endl;
} else {
    // Do stuff with person
}
```